# React Bootstrap Table delete button onclick dont work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have created a table in which I would now like to be able to delete individual rows. The button is displayed and can be clicked, but the deleteItmen function is not called. Unfortunately I'm quite new to React.js and haven't found a solution yet.

```
const Tab = (props) => {
const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const token = getUser.getCurrentUser().token;

useEffect(() => {
    LoadTable();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);

const LoadTable = () => {
    if (props.table === undefined)
        getData("device", setShowContent, setLoading);
    else getData(props.table, setShowContent, setLoading);
};

const getHeader = () => {
    return <tr>{showContent[0].map((elem, index) => <th>{elem}</th>)}</tr>
}

const getBody = () => {
    const bodylist = Object.values(showContent.slice(1));
    const body = bodylist.map((elem, index) => ({ ...elem, button: (<button onclick={() => deleteItem(elem.id)}>Delete</button>) }))
    return body.map((row, index) => <tr> {Object.values(row).map((elem, i) => <td> {elem}</td>)} </tr>)
}

const deleteItem = async (id) => {
    await axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/' + id, { tablename: props.table }, {
        headers: {
            "x-access-token": token,
        },
    })
    LoadTable();
}

return (
    <div>
        {!loading ?
            <h1>Loading</h1> :

            <table>
                <thead>{getHeader()}</thead>
                <tbody>{getBody()}</tbody>
            </table>
        }
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Change ```onclick``` to ```onClick``` .. The letter ```C``` needs to be in uppercase..

Comment: Thank you, I probably overlooked that. Now it works.